# onclick и innerHTML

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему событие `onclick` в коде ниже не выполняется. Если убрать последнюю строку с `innerHTML`, всё работает:

```js
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = "Default message";
div.onclick = function(){this.innerHTML = 'Onclick message'}
document.body.appendChild(div);
document.body.innerHTML += 'Next line';
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Любое [изменение свойства *innerHTML*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) приводит к полной замене всех элементов.

Таким образом, после выполнения

```
document.body.innerHTML += 'Next line';
```

элемент `div`, которому был добавлен обработчик, был удален, и вместо него теперь *новый* div, которому обработчик не добавляли.

Для решения можно или собрать всю строку сразу, и лишь затем навесить обработчики

```js
var div = `<div id="div">Default message</div>`;
document.body.innerHTML += div;
document.body.innerHTML += 'Next line';

document.getElementById('div').onclick = function() {
  this.innerHTML = 'Onclick message'
}
```

или не использовать `innerHTML`, а создавать элементы напрямую:

```js
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = "Default message";
div.onclick = function() {
  this.innerHTML = 'Onclick message'
}
document.body.appendChild(div);
var textNode = document.createTextNode('Next line');
document.body.appendChild(textNode);
```

Альтернативным способом добавления разметки, [как подсказывают в комментариях](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/637214/onclick-%D0%B8-innerhtml/637218?noredirect=1#comment900809_637218), может стать использование [метода insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

```js
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = "Default message";
div.onclick = function() {
  this.innerHTML = 'Onclick message'
}
document.body.appendChild(div);
div.insertAdjacentHTML('afterEnd', 'Next line');
```

Comment: Вообще всё тут странно сделано. **По логике** оно не должно всё заменять, а просто добавить к существующему коду новую строку. Инвалидский язык :)

Comment: @Yuri, язык тут не причем, это работа с DOM. Сделано именно по логике: innerHTML - это **весь HTML**, после его присвоения он должен быть разобран заново и отрендерен, что и происходит.

Comment: А можно ли как-то перед заменой сохранить все функции всех элементов, а потом опять тем же элементам?)

Comment: @Yuri, добавил варианты решения.

Comment: Ну эти решения я знаю. Но вот если уже присвоил все функции и в процессе работы с сайтом изменяется `innerHTML`. Можно ли каким-то образом забрать все события перед записью, а потом заново присвоить? Я знаю, что можно записать присваивание событий в функцию и потом вызывать её.

Comment: Не грех упомянуть `insertAdjacent*`.

Comment: @Other, Добавил с ним пример

Comment: [зануда]Почему не `insertAdjacentText`?[/зануда]

Comment: @Other, потому что html :)